# Responsive views of multiple boostrap buttons placed on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 5 bootstrap buttons placed side by side on the same line. They look fine on desktop. Screenshot-

[image]

But on smaller viewport, the buttons are placed over two lines without any spacing between the lines. As a result they look odd. Screenshot-

[image]

I am wanting to keep some vertical spacing between the lines on responsive view so they look similar to this-

[image]

I want to make it so that there is always a line spacing there irrespective of the number of buttons on the same line or total number of lines on responsive view.

Is there any way to do this with bootstrap?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: try using this `button{margin:10px;}` Give margin where you want  Check This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rzdcxgr5/

Comment: @parish it worked. thanks for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this `button{margin:10px;}` Give margin where you want

Check This fiddle

jsfiddle.net/rzdcxgr5